# How use two multimarkers in scene Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, artoolkit

I'm trying to use two multimarkers in my Unity 3D and ARToolKit project, but is not working. Can I do this, how I do?
I need to use multimarkers, because I need to capture the rotational movement of each.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what your problem is, it works fine out of the box.

In the ARMarker class there is a dropdown box where you can select the marker type (be it square, square barcode, multimarker or NFT), so you just set it to multimarker and select the proper marker file.

Also, inside the Example Scenes directory there is one called MultimarkerScene, which should be exactly what you are looking for. I just tried it with the default multimarker cube and it works.

The default multimarker pdf can be found into the SDK docs/patterns folder, but I see that it is not included in the Unity package, but is in the Android or iOS one. You can see how the cube look like here (3rd photo) http://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=3_Marker_Training:marker_multi

Comment: The example MultimarkerScene uses only one multimarker in the scene, what I need is to use two multimarker the scene. Thanks.

Comment: Then you need to define 2 multimarker files and use add them as ARMarkers, same as you would do for single markers.